# upload file with --upload-file to server

Tags: rest, file-upload, asp.net-core, put

I'm currently trying to create a rest endpoint to upload a file with curl.

For this I want to use the awesome builtin parameter called `--upload-file` which uploads a file to a server.

[This has the following properties](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T):

- Sends a PUT
- Url path is the filename

E.g `curl --upload-file "texts/test.txt" http://localhost/`

It sends a `PUT` request to `http://localhost/file.txt`

How can I now define a action inside a controller to catch all put request?

I've tried it with:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public string UploadFilePut() {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public string UploadFilePut(IFormFile file) {
    }
}
```

but both of them don't work.

Edit:

```
curl localhost:57623 --upload-file diamond.sh -v
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--         0*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 57623 (#0)
> PUT /diamond.sh HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:57623
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1987
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [1987 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 17:47:09 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Content-Length: 0
<
100  1987    0     0  100  1987      0  64096 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     64096
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

And on the server:

```
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 PUT http://localhost:57623/diamond.sh  1987
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 13.7902ms 404
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you get a 404?  Using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) does Content-Type header show as multipart/form-data?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting a 404. I've edited the post with an example.

Comment: From the [manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T) it says "If there is no file part in the specified URL, curl will append the local file name".  So you need to change your command to `curl --upload-file "texts/test.txt" http://localhost/index`.

Comment: And how would I do it anyway? I know that I can just specify the proper path, but what if I don't want to include that. There needs to be a option/method for that.

Comment: You need to use [Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing), something like `[HttpPut("{filename}.{ext?}")]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark G, this is how to do it properly:

```
[HttpPut("{filename}.{ext?}")]
[ActionName("Index")]
public void UploadPut(string filename, string ext) {
    var tmp = new FileInfo("temp");

    Console.WriteLine($"Writing {filename}.{ext} to {tmp.FullName}");
    using (var fs = tmp.OpenWrite()) {
        Request.Body.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}
```